# Bootstrap 3 Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap-3

I think I almost have Bootstrap validation working but it seems buggy or i'm missing something. When using an input-group how do I make the icon show up in the text field. The other problem is when it errors out and the user fixes it the x icon is still there instead of a checkbox.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8RELb/57/)

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        field1: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        field2: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error')
        $(element).next('span').removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success')
        $(element).next('span').removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
    },
    //errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, the next sibling can be the error message label not the feedback

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        field1: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        field2: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error')
        $(element).parent().find('.form-control-feedback').removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        $(element).parent().find('.form-control-feedback').removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
    },
    //errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2dkGx/)

Comment: That's great. Any idea how to make the checkbox fit in the input group text field on the first one?